# Usage of asterisk at the end of command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, wildcard

I know that asterisk is used in regular expressions, but what is the meaning of it at the end of the line?

```
find . -type f | grep -sl 'word' *
```

I know I can get similar results using

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -sl 'while'
```

Comment: using * at the end means throughout the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asterisk `*` at the end is used to check in the list of files in your directory in lexicographic order.

Comment: So the command takes the output of find and gives it grep as arguments in alphabetical order?

Comment: @DPosnas No. The `find` output is ignored. `grep` only uses stdin if told so - which can happen by providing no files at all or by providing `-` as a file name.

Comment: So `grep` does iterate the current directory to get the file names and checks for the pattern?

Comment: No (in this invocation, `grep` does not iterate the current directory); the shell expands the `*` into a sorted list of file names; `grep` just reads the list of file names it is given.  If you had the `-r` option, then `grep` would scan directories.  You are still wasting the effort `find` puts into finding names.  Check on the `-exec` option with `+`, and on `xargs` (and `-print0` and `-0`).  Lots of answers on SO covering all this.